# Imagnes en Angular desde API

Tags: html, angular, api, select

Buenas Tardes a todos los compañeros Tengo una duda
Tengo una api de paises que tienen su bandera pero quiero mostrar el nombre del pais y su bandera en un select en Angular si me pudieran ayudar se los agradeceria mucho

Comment: Debes incluir un [example] de lo que has hecho y donde te has encallado y los errores que te hayan dado. Lo siento, no se nos permite realizar código a medida y tu pregunta no cumple con lo esperado en este sitio para ser válida. Puede ser cerrada o recibir votos negativos. Léete [ask] para aprender cómo deben ser las preguntas en este sitio para ser consideradas válidas, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.